# How to program my Mac to automatically type text when pressing a key

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, automator

How do I program my Mac's <kbd>F19</kbd> key to automatically type a text when I press it?

Answer (score 4):

#### If you want to use any keyboard shortcut, with built-in methods …

Open up *Automator.app* and create a new *Service*. Set it to receive *no input* and drag *Run AppleScript* from the left pane to the right.

Enter this script:

```
tell application "System Events"
    keystroke "your-text.com"
end tell
```

Save the service under any name you like. Normally, you'd assign shortcuts to services by going to *System Preferences » Keyboard » Keyboard Shortcuts*. Here, you can assign (almost) any key combination.

However, in OS X 10.6, there's a bug that won't let you assign a service to an F-key. See the second option in my answer on how to overcome that. In 10.7 it seems to work though.

---

#### If you want to use third-party software …

Open up *AppleScript Editor.app* and paste the script from above. Save it under `~/Library/Scripts`. You need to create this folder before if it doesn't exist. If your Library is hidden, in Finder press <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> and enter `~/Library` to view it.

Then, after you've saved the script, you can install [FastScripts](http://www.red-sweater.com/fastscripts/) and bind that script to <kbd>F19</kbd> (or whatever you like).

[image]

Comment: 10.7.4 seems to allow using just F-keys as shortcuts for services.

Comment: Good to know they've resolved this.

Answer (score 4):

You could also create ~/Library/KeyBindings/ and save a property list like this as DefaultKeyBinding.dict.

```
{
    "\UF716" = (insertText:, "test");
}
```

Applications have to be reopened to apply changes. For more information, see http://www.hcs.harvard.edu/~jrus/Site/Cocoa%20Text%20System.html or http://lri.me/keybindings.html.